# Deploy with New-AzureWebsiteJob and dotnet core?

Tags: powershell, azure, .net-core, azure-webjobs

I have an azure webjob that I can deploy fine through visual studio, right click publish etc. all that is fine. I am using Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs beta 3.0 against .NET Core 2.0. Of course when that project is built it creates a set of .dlls and no direct executable as is normal for .net core.

Now I want to create an integration test suite which will deploy my webjob to azure with Powershell, using [New-AzureWebsiteJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/new-azurewebsitejob?view=azuresmps-4.0.0). When I publish this way I get

```
New-AzureWebsiteJob : No runnable script file was found.
```

As far as I can gather my job file should have either: batch (.exe/.cmd/.bat), bash (.sh), javascript (.js as node.js), php (.php) or python (.py). If so what magic does VS do, and how should I go about scripting this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found the solution. It is, however, inelegant. Create a file run.bat or similar containing

```
@ECHO OFF
dotnet YourLibraryName.dll
```

and include that in any zip file uploading with the cmdlet. More [here](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/deploy-net-core-console-application-based-azure-webjob-using-powershell/)